# Trouble binding events/popups to existing leaflet geojson layer

Tags: json, popup, leaflet, layer, geojson

I am trying to add local json data to a GeoJson layer in Leaflet, and then (for now) bind a popup to each feature in the json. The trouble is that I am unable to first create a geojson layer, and then later bind popups. Is there any way to do this? I am only able to create the layer and add the popups at the same time.  What I have so far:

Create the map.

```
map = new L.Map('map');
```

Grab the local json file:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "name": "Denver",
            "amenity": "Baseball Stadium",
            "popupContent": "This is where the Rockies play!"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-102.99404, 37.75621]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "name": "Baltimore",
            "amenity": "Baseball Stadium",
            "popupContent": "This is where the Orioles play!"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-76.6167, 39.2833]
        }
    }
    ]
}
```

and send json through to plotData():

```
function plotData( data ) 
{
  var pointLayer = L.geoJson().addTo(map);

  // 1. works
  L.geoJson(data, {
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
  }).addTo(map);


  // 2. does not bind popups
  pointLayer.addData( data, {
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
      }
  );

  // 3. Error - invalid GeoJson Object
  pointLayer.addData( L.geoJson(data, {
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
      })
  );
}

function onEachFeature( feature, layer ) 
{
  layer.bindPopup( feature.properties.name );
}
```

The markers display just fine on the map for scenario 1 and 2 (with 1 also displaying popups). Now, is there any reason why I should not be trying to first create the layer and then bind actions to the features?  Is it better practice to just do what I have stated in 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third option won't work, because you're feeding `L.Layer` object where a GeoJSON object should go. `L.GeoJSON.addData()` function does not have `onEachFeature` parameter. Basically, when you have processed a GeoJSON, its feature properties are gone.

There are two ways to proceed.

```
// create empty GeoJSON layer
var pointLayer = L.geoJson(null, { onEachFeature: storeName }).addTo(map);
// add data to it later, invoking storeName() function
pointLayer.addData(data);
// which stores names
function storeName(f, l) { l._gname = f.properties.name; }
// and when you're ready...
pointLayer.eachLayer(addPopupFromGName);
// add popups with stored name
function addPopupFromGName(l) { l.bindPopup(l._gname); }
```

Or just add `onEachFeature` function to L.GeoJSON layer options:

```
var pointLayer = L.geoJson(null, { onEachFeature: onEachFeature }).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!  I had it figured out a couple hours after posting but could not answer my own question so soon because of my low rep :(, but my solution is the same as yours.